# How to connect android mobile game to redis?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, redis

I am working on a mobile game with Unity. I try to use Redis to store some shared data for users. My problem is that I can establish the connection to Redis with a c# Reids-cli on the computer but I cannot connect to Redis anymore after I deployed the game into an android phone. (Platform not supported error)

I want to know if there are some redis-clis I can use to connect to redis from android devices. Or I need to export some libraries into .apk to make the c# redis-clis work in the android environment?

Comment: Are you creating a privately distributed app?  You typically don't want to expose Redis directly to anything like an app you'd put on an appstore publicly.  https://redis.io/topics/security

Comment: Thanks for the advice.but I still dont know how to mediate access between Redis and untrusted clients in this case. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: For our apps, we use: Unity3D > Socket.IO (Node.js) > Redis

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into it.